# Display records using php to a javascript clock

Tags: javascript, php

I need to have a static clock. I have a code below which displayed database records(hours, Minutes, Seconds) 
dynamically in a clock statically. 
My problem is that its only the first clock that has (hours, Minutes, Seconds) displayed.
 the rest of the clock shows 00:00:00 when displayed dynamically.
I think the problem is in the Javascript id that renders the clock data.

Can someone help me with that. Below is the code

```
<?php
require('db[enter image description here][1].php');

/*
create table info_timing(id int primary key auto_increment, time_hour varchar(100),time_minute varchar(100),
time_seconds varchar(100), informatia varchar(100));

insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('04','30','57','My First Data');
insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('06','20','01','My Second Data');
insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('07','45','36','My Third Data');
*/


$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM info_timing order by id desc");
        $data->execute(array());


while ($row = $data->fetch()) 
{
$id =  htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$th =  htmlentities($row['time_hour'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); 
$tm =  htmlentities($row['time_minute'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$ts =  htmlentities($row['time_seconds'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$info =  htmlentities($row['informatia'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
//}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>

function clock(){
    //calculate angle
    var d, h, m, s;
    d = new Date;

/*
h1 = 15;
h2 = 22;
h3 = 11;
*/


h1 = '<?php echo $th; ?>';
h2 = '<?php echo $tm; ?>';
h3 = '<?php echo $ts; ?>';


h = 30 * ((h1 % 12) );
    m = 6 * h2;
    s = 6 * h3;


    //move hands
    setAttr('h-hand', h);
    setAttr('m-hand', m);
    setAttr('s-hand', s);
    setAttr('s-tail', s+180);

    //display time

    h = h1;
    m = h2;
    s = h3;


    if(h >= 12){
        setText('suffix', 'PM');
    }else{
        setText('suffix', 'AM');
    }

    if(h != 12){
        h %= 12;
    }

    setText('sec', s);
    setText('min', m);
    setText('hr', h);

    //call every second
    setTimeout(clock, 1000);

};

function setAttr(id,val){
    var v = 'rotate(' + val + ', 70, 70)';
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', v);
};

function setText(id,val){
    if(val < 10){
        val = '0' + val;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};

window.onload=clock;


</script>

<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

.analog-clock{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
}

#clock-face{
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:2px;
    fill:white;
}

#h-hand, #m-hand, #s-hand, #s-tail{
    stroke:black;
    stroke-linecap:round;
}

#h-hand{
    stroke-width:3px;
}

#m-hand{
    stroke-width:2px;
}

#s-hand{
    stroke-width:1px;
}

.time-text{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<b>Id:</b> <?php echo $id; ?><br>
<b>Information:</b> <?php echo $info; ?><br>
<b>Hours:</b> <?php echo $th; ?><br>
<b>Minutes:</b> <?php echo $tm; ?><br>
<b>Seconds:</b> <?php echo $ts; ?><br>

        <div class="analog-clock">
            <svg width="140" height="140">
                <circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
                <line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
                <line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
                <line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
                <line id="s-tail" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="56" />
                <text x="62" y="18">12</text>
                <text x="126" y="76">3</text>
                <text x="66" y="130">6</text>
                <text x="7" y="76">9</text>
            </svg>
            <div class="time-text">
                <span id="hr">00</span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span id="min">00</span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span id="sec">00</span>
                <span id="suffix">--</span>
            </div>
        </div>
<br><br>

<?php
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also attached the screenshot

Comment: I put your code in a snipplet and replaced the php with just the variables you commented out and it ran fine. Not sure what your issue is. Is there an error in the console?

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
<?php require('db[enter image description here][1].php');

/* create table info_timing(id int primary key auto_increment, time_hour varchar(100),time_minute varchar(100), time_seconds varchar(100), informatia varchar(100));

insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('04','30','57','My First Data'); insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('06','20','01','My Second Data'); insert into info_timing(time_hour,time_minute,time_seconds,informatia)values('07','45','36','My Third Data');
*/


$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM info_timing order by id desc");
        $data->execute(array());


while ($row = $data->fetch())  { $id =  htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); $th =  htmlentities($row['time_hour'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");  $tm =  htmlentities($row['time_minute'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); $ts =  htmlentities($row['time_seconds'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); $info =  htmlentities($row['informatia'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); //} ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>

      $(window).on('load', function(){
            clock();
        });


</script>

<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; }

.analog-clock{
    width:140px;
    height:140px; }

#clock-face{
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:2px;
    fill:white; }

#h-hand, #m-hand, #s-hand, #s-tail{
    stroke:black;
    stroke-linecap:round; }

#h-hand{
    stroke-width:3px; }

#m-hand{
    stroke-width:2px; }

#s-hand{
    stroke-width:1px; }

.time-text{
    text-align:center; } </style>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body> <b>Id:</b> <?php echo $id; ?><br> <b>Information:</b> <?php echo $info; ?><br> <b>Hours:</b> <?php echo $th; ?><br> <b>Minutes:</b> <?php echo $tm; ?><br> <b>Seconds:</b> <?php echo $ts; ?><br>

        <div class="analog-clock">
            <svg width="140" height="140">
                <circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
                <line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
                <line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
                <line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
                <line id="s-tail" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="56" />
                <text x="62" y="18">12</text>
                <text x="126" y="76">3</text>
                <text x="66" y="130">6</text>
                <text x="7" y="76">9</text>
            </svg>
            <div class="time-text">
                <span id="hr">00</span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span id="min">00</span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span id="sec">00</span>
                <span id="suffix">--</span>
            </div>
        </div> <br><br>

<?php } ?>
    </body>
<script>
         function clock(){
    //calculate angle
    var d, h, m, s;
    d = new Date;

/* h1 = 15; h2 = 22; h3 = 11;
*/


h1 = '<?php echo $th; ?>'; h2 = '<?php echo $tm; ?>'; h3 = '<?php echo $ts; ?>';


h = 30 * ((h1 % 12) );
    m = 6 * h2;
    s = 6 * h3;


    //move hands
    setAttr('h-hand', h);
    setAttr('m-hand', m);
    setAttr('s-hand', s);
    setAttr('s-tail', s+180);

    //display time

    h = h1;
    m = h2;
    s = h3;


    if(h >= 12){
        setText('suffix', 'PM');
    }else{
        setText('suffix', 'AM');
    }

    if(h != 12){
        h %= 12;
    }

    setText('sec', s);
    setText('min', m);
    setText('hr', h);

    //call every second
    setTimeout(clock, 1000);

};

function setAttr(id,val){
    var v = 'rotate(' + val + ', 70, 70)';
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', v); };

function setText(id,val){
    if(val < 10){
        val = '0' + val;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val; };

</script>
```

Comment: At Alvaro Alves, It doesn't work. it show 00 : 00 : 00 --  for all the clock instead of the actual hours, minutes, seconds as displayed from database. from the console, it shows error clock2.php:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at clock2.php:21
(anonymous) @ clock2.php:21
clock2.php:59 GET http://localhost/project2018/web/wall/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
clock2.php:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at clock2.php:91
(anonymous) @ clock2.php:91
clock2.php:129 GET